# Why is my TouchScript gesture event not firing?

Tags: unity, touch

I am using TouchScript (v9.0) with Unity (2018.2.14f1) and am struggling with getting the `Flicked` gesture event to fire. I created an empty game object with a few UI elements in it (text and raw images) and added the `Flick Gesture` component to it (didn't change any of the settings on it), along with a custom script I wrote to register the `Flicked` event - this code is mostly from the [wiki](https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript/wiki/Gestures):

```
public class FlickGestureHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    FlickGesture gesture;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gesture = GetComponent<FlickGesture>();

        if (gesture != null)
        {
            gesture.Flicked += flickedHandler;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Gesture is null...");
        }
    }

    public void flickedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        print("Flick gesture recorded");
    }
}
```

I've also added an empty and added a `Touch Manager` component to it, although I don't know if that does anything by itself, or how to connect it to my draggable game object.

When I run the app, I wait for the gameobject's contents to appear (I am using Keyframe animation and the UI elements do not appear until a few seconds after load), then try to drag the UI elements in any direction and nothing is printed to the console. I am using a touch screen monitor and a touch pen for this. Why is the event not firing? FWIW, I tried creating a simpler example where I just attach the scripts (`Flick Gesture` and my custom script `Flick Gesture Handler`) to an image object and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem

After I created a scene object as parent of a camera it suddenly worked

Comment: Are you sure that with this procedure your problem has been solved? If not, I recommend commenting instead of creating a answer.